# Adding dynamic metadata in header with Gruntjs

Tags: gruntjs

I have a **header.html** file that is included by *grunt-processhtml* in all others html files.

My header file contains the tags "`<head>`" and "`</head>`", the others html's files (for example, **index.html**) include the header calling the following command:

```
<!-- build:include layout/header.html --><!-- /build -->
```

I would like to have a metadata (for example `<meta name='x'content='y'>`) generated dynamically for my application for each page. It's easily read from the all html files. But, I wonder if is possible to "header.html" include the metadata from "index.html" or any other html file.

Remembering that header.html is in the top of the hierarchy, so a "son" file should be include in his "parent".

Or... Have some better way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're at the point when it becomes worth it to look at a fully fledged template system (Zetzer, Mustache, Handlebars, Jade,...) - or even a full-blown site generator maybe (assemble, metalsmith,..), depending on your context. They all have grunt plugins afaik.

This would let you do your requirement easily, and open further possibilities, like generating more of your html from your data.